# Dovecot configuration files using `remote` syntax not being honored

Tags: dovecot

According to the Dovecot documentation, one can [alter configuration directives](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/config_file/config_file_syntax/) based on the protocol, as well as the local and remote IPs.

In my current setup (Mail-in-a-box using Nextcloud, which uses IMAP authentication), my mail logs are spammed with local logins. I really don't need these reports, but still want to retain login logs for remote IPs.

I set the following in my configuration:

```
remote 127.0.0.1 {
  info_log_path = /dev/null
}
```

When I run `doveadm -n -f remote=127.0.0.1`, this appears to be registered correctly:

```
# 2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967)
...
info_log_path = /dev/null
...
remote 127.0.0.1 {
  info_log_path = /dev/null
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm still getting spammed with login reports when the local and remote IPs are both localhost.

```
Aug 12 12:17:13 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<user@domain.tld>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=29798, TLS, session=<FGVJhbCsstt/AAAB>
Aug 12 12:17:13 imap(user@domain.tld): Info: Logged out in=305 out=2277
```

I've also tried logging to a specific file, instead of /dev/null, but no file was created. So there must be an issue with my understanding. Anyone else successfully able to use these conditionals in their configuration?